# Cant get jQuery ajax POST to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

If I set type to 'GET' in the code below it works, but I cant get it to work with 'POST'.

ajaxPostTest.html...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxPostTest_server.php",
        data: {"fruit1": "rasp", "fruit2": "bramble"},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            $("#returned").append(data.fruit1);
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert("error") ;
            }
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="returned">returned: </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxPostTest_server.php...

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
?>
```

The expected output on the browser is...

```
returned: rasp
```

I'm actually attempting to interact with an ASP.NET web server and I want to confirm my ajax is working (and I understand ajax properly) first - hence this simplified code.

Firebug debugging...

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Fri, 23 Sep 2011 14:57:37 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.1
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost/My_Webs/temp/ajaxPostText1.html
Content-Length  26
Cookie  PHPSESSID=mgvoacnluh3kad5pakafrd5kd1
```

All I get in the 'response' tab is...

```
{"PHPSESSID":"mgvoacnluh3kad5pakafrd5kd1"}
```

I.e. I cant find where the data I send to the server is going to.

Comment: Can you use firebug and post the error, or the response from the console?

Comment: Why do you set the content-type of your request to "application/json"? Set it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (the default) and try again.

Comment: @AJC. Added response to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your sending your data as "application/json", PHP does not populate $_POST / $_REQUEST. You need to send the request as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (you can leave out the "Content-Type" parameter because this is the default type).

Comment: That worked. I had added the Content-Type cos that seems to be used when communicating with ASP.NET rather than PHP. Also GET doesnt seem to mind adding the json content-type. Anyway now I know what the rules are I can get it to work. Thanks for your solution and time.

Answer (score 0):

use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: Thanks. Tried that - no effect.