# Getting Json Form Data in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js

This might seem like an unordinary **json** question but I can assure you I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

In the code example below I would like to get (possibly **decode** the json data that is being transferred. I've tried **json_decode($_POST)**. By the way the request type is **POST**. Is there anyway I can obtain the json data into an array or a variable so when I would like to call **name** or **age** I will easily retrieve them from request?

I'm following a **backbone.js** tutorial and here is my model;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var URL=Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function()
            {
                console.log("URL has been initialized");
            },
            defaults:{
                name:'not defined',
                age:'not defined'
            },
            urlRoot:"/Backbone/manage.php",
            url:function(){
                var base = this.urlRoot || (this.collection && this.collection.url) || "/";
                console.log("Base has been produced");
                if(this.isNew()) return base;

                return base+"?id="+encodeURIComponent(this.id);
            }
        });

        var url=new URL({name:"John",age:10});
        url.save();
    </script>
```

Later on I use Google Chrome in order to watch the network and I can clear see that the data is passed as **form data**. Here is the result in Google's Network Tool;

```
model:{"name":"John","age":10}
```

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST);` to see which field name carries the payload, if any. It doesn't just show up as `$_POST` with raw data. It would be `json_decode($_POST["varname"])` (e.g. `"id"`, but that's your issue) or possibly reside in `php://input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting JSON payload as raw post data you can read it with:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You could also read it from `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` if php.ini settings allow for that variable do be filled.

Since what you are getting is:

```
model=%7B%22name%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22age%22%3A10%7D
```

You can't directly decode it as JSON because it's not valid JSON.

So try:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $post);
$myObject = json_decode($post['model']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried `$modelData=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo "Name : ".$modelData->name;` but it didn't work

Comment: try `var_dump($modelData);` it may be something different from what you expect. Also try `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` to see if you are getting anything at all

Comment: I've tried the last edit you did and it prints nothing. Both tried '$myObject->name' and '$myObject[0]->name'

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` ? If it shows you nothing or NULL any further code is not even worth trying because you are not getting any data. Have you tried displaying what your script has in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ?

Comment: Tried it right now. It prints: string(52) "model=%7B%22name%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22age%22%3A10%7D"

Comment: Latest Update: I've commented my emulateJSON and emulateHTTP codes and I've used `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` which resulted as 'string(24) "{"name":"John","age":10}" '.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do json_decode on the `model` key of the $_POST array. The `model` key contains the json string that you need to decode.

```
$modelData = json_decode($_POST['model']);
```

Then you can access the data like `$modelData->name` or `$modelData->age`;

EDIT:

Try adding this to your backbone set up:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
```

This will make it so you are getting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. This should then populate your $_POST array correctly.

See here for explanation: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-162

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. It seemed quite reasonable to me too thus I've tried: `$modelData = json_decode($_POST['model']);
echo "Name : ".$modelData->name;` but didn't work

Comment: What does print_r on your $_POST variable give you?

Comment: it prints 1 and somehow now I can get a type 'Array
(
    [model] => {\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":10}
)' with @Kamil Szot's solution

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why your Post array is not populating correctly. Does populate correctly with a regular form post?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530862/cant-get-jquery-ajax-post-to-work. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: You may need to turn use `Backbone.emulateHTTP`, so it will send requests `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `application/json`

Comment: @rolandbishop. That's called magic quotes. And there is no need for lengthy poking-in-the-dark-chats here on Stackoverflow. Post relevant information with your question next time.

Comment: @Gohn67 I've did everything your edit and written `$modelData = json_decode($_POST['model']);
if($modelData==NULL)
 echo "Fail";
else
 echo "Success";` which outputted 'Fail'